# Call in and out methods given variadic args from a variadic template container class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I need to get rid of old c++98 variadic syntax and use modern c++-17 variadic templates and args for supporting in and out calls of (runtime) functions and interpreter functions.

I am actually trying to ...test the mechanics of it:

```
template<typename C, typename R, typename ...A>
class methodology{

    std::string _name;

    C* rt_obj = nullptr;

    using rt_fn_t = R(C::*)(A...);
    rt_fn_t rt_fn = nullptr;
    //using out_fn_t  = alu(const alu::list_t& params);

public:
    // `alu` is a custom std::any wrapper container class:
    // Kind of Arithmetic Logical Unit. 

    // teasing js dangerous style
    std::string& name() { return _name; }

    // Runtime calling a given "named" function into the interpreter:
    R operator()(const A& ...args){ 
        // pack into our alu list:        
        auto param = [](auto a){
            return alu(a);
        };

        alu::list_t params = { param(args)...};
        alu a = interpreter::enter(_name, params);

        return a.value<R>();
    }

    /*
       Called from inside the interpreter:
    */
    alu operator()(const alu::list_t& params){
        // Here is my lack of c++ 17 functional knowledges:
        //how to : params => A..args, using this class's typename ...A ???
        return (rt_obj->*rt_fn)(args...);
        return alu(false); // default. Unimplemented.
    }
};
```

My problems:
(Please, consult my "alu" class header file if more details are needed: 
https://github.com/bretzel/xio/blob/master/xio%2B%2B/interpreter/kernel/alu.hpp, and then to view the actual old ugly syntax:
https://github.com/bretzel/xio/blob/master/xio%2B%2B/interpreter/kernel/function_t.hpp)

`std::apply(...,std::tuple<>)` seems the way to go but:
How do I build an `std::tuple<(methodology<typename...A>)>` from the list of "`alu`", which each "`alu`" deeply holds the argument type into its inner "`std::any`" object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand what do you want and how your `alu` works but... I suppose you're looking something as follows (caution: code not verified; sorry)

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
alu op_helper (alu::list_t const & params, std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
 { return (rt_obj->*rt_fn)(params[Is].value<A>()...); }

auto operator() (alu::list_t const & params)
 { return op_helper(params, std::index_sequence_for<A...>{}); }
```

Off Topic: given that your `alu` class holds a limited and known set of possible types, isn't better `std::variant` instead of `std::any`?

Comment: @BenVoigt - D'Oh! Yes: `std::variant`; corrected; thanks!

Comment: OMG! Sir max66, you're my hero! I could never ever get to think about that construct. Do you realize that thanks to you, you just made possible to do full duplex? :) 

Infinitely thankful, Sir.

Comment: Btw, about std::variant, I could but I must exactly handle integers from int8_t to uint_64_t, then double; + strings, void*, xio_t*... :)